# tailwind + alpinejs - how can i auto position dropdown(or drop-up) menu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css, alpine.js

here is my code; https://codepen.io/islamkaya/pen/dyqeMrG

> In the example on Codepen, when you click on the button located at the far right of the last row of the table, the dropdown menu that opens scrolls down. If there is not enough space to display the dropdown below the container, I want to move it upwards using Alpine.js. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z46xG.png)

```
  function toggleDropdown() {
    const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
    if (dropdownMenu.style.display === "none") {
      dropdownMenu.style.display = "block";
      const rect = dropdownMenu.getBoundingClientRect();
      const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      console.log(windowHeight, rect.bottom);
      if (rect.bottom > windowHeight) {
        dropdownMenu.style.bottom = "100%";
        dropdownMenu.style.top = "auto";
        console.log("1");
      }
    } else {
      dropdownMenu.style.display = "none";
      dropdownMenu.style.bottom = "auto";
      dropdownMenu.style.top = "100%";
      console.log("2");
    }
  }
```

I have positioned the menu either up or down based on the browser size using vanilla JavaScript, but I couldn't do this within its container

Comment: hi, the codepen do not show the function you tried, can you update it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used, hopefully it will help you.
It works both for top, bottom, left and right. Starting positions are bottom and left

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ezehkingsleyuchenna/pen/bGmqvQE

```
<div x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }" @keydown.window.escape="dropdownOpen = false" @click.away="dropdownOpen = false" x-ref="ts">
    <button
        @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" type="button"
        class="
            inline-flex justify-center px-4
                text-sm leading-5 font-medium
                focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue
                bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 border border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700
                text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800
                rounded-full h-10 w-10 flex items-center transition ease-in-out duration-150"
        aria-haspopup="true" x-bind:aria-expanded="dropdownOpen" aria-expanded="true">
        <span>
            ...label...
        </span>
    </button>

    <div class="relative">
        <div
            x-data="{
            'style': {'tb': 'bottom', 'lr': 'left'},
            checkSize () {
                let size = $el.scrollHeight || $refs.ts.getBoundingClientRect().top || 88,
                sizeBottom = $el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom || $refs.ts.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
                sizeLeft = $el.getBoundingClientRect().left || $refs.ts.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                let arr = {'tb': 'bottom', 'lr': 'left'};
                if ((window.innerHeight - sizeBottom) < (size + $el.offsetHeight)) arr.tb = 'top';
                if (sizeLeft < 200) arr.lr = 'right';
                return arr;
            }
        }"
            x-init="style = checkSize();"
            @resize.window="style = checkSize();"
            x-show="dropdownOpen"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
            x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
            x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            class="origin-top-right absolute mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-40 border dark:border-gray-700 right-0"
            :class="{ 'bottom-10': style.tb === 'top', 'right-0': style.lr === 'left' }"
            style="display: none;"
        >
            <div class="rounded-md bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 shadow-xs">
                <div class="py-1" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="options-menu">
                    ...dropdown items here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```